# Issue with website testing using Google PageSpeed while decryption is enabled on firewall

Tags: encryption, firewall, pagespeed

We are experiencing is issue when testing our web-site using Google's PageSpeed Insights tool (https://pagespeed.web.dev/) when decryption is enabled on our firewall for inbound traffic.

When decryption is enabled, PageSpeed Insights displays the following error:

> Unable to resolve https://XXXX.XXXX.com/. Try checking the URL for validity.

However, when we disable the decryption policy, the website can be analyzed without any issues.

Does PageSpeed not support analyzing traffic while decryption is enabled?